# How do you expand /var in pfsense when you run it in memory?

Tags: networking, firewall, freebsd, pfsense, bsd

I have a pfsense box running 32GBs of RAM. I enabled /var and other directories to be in RAM due to have so much space and wanted to improve performance.

How do you alter and increase the size of /var in RAM?

I've looked in the settings and I see no options to change the size.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It's right there in front of your nose. :)

Generally speaking, though, you should limit the amount of data you're storing on your pfsense instance. For logs, ship them off to another loghost for analysis and long-term storage.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that! Have the logs going offserver right now. I was pushing all the squid cache to RAM for faster processing and just noticed it was maxing out the /var. Thanks!

Comment: You may be overthinking this RAM thing. Frequently-used files will be cached in RAM anyway, even with an on-disk file system.

Comment: To be found in :     System / Advanced / Miscellaneous or /system_advanced_misc.php